# dataframe.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan) does not work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So basically a column in dataframe has Nan and float, I want to use apply to calculate the value in the column. If the value is nan, then return else, calculate.

But looks like `x is np.nan` in lambda does not give me the right answer. here is an example

```
In[6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

In[7]: df.A.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan)
Out[7]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as a duplicate of a question that doesn't even talk about `is`, but at least I found another question about that, though for NumPy.

Comment: It looks like the only difference from the NumPy question is that Pandas returns a plain `float` from a float64 column. Although IDK if maybe that's an implementation detail or platform-specific, or there's other nuance to it. From a quick test, if I use a more precise dtype than the builtin, like float128, the result is `numpy.float128` instead of `float`, whereas if I use a less precise dtype like float32 or float16, I still get `float`. And ofc, if I use 'object', everything works as you originally expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first.  To get what you want:

```
df.A.isnull()
```

Secondly, `np.nan` is not comparable.  By design `np.nan == np.nan` is False.

To get around this, pandas and numpy have specific functions to test if it is null.  You could:

```
df.A.apply(pd.isnull)
```

But that is the same thing as:

```
df.A.isnull()
```

That I mentioned above.

Comment: *"By design `np.nan == np.nan` is False."* — What does that have to do with the question? OP's asking about `is`, which is totally different from `==`, no? I found [a question about the same thing, but for NumPy](/q/52123892/numpy-nan-not-always-recognized) (and added it as a duplicate). It looks like the actual problem is that a new NaN is created every time, cause if I do `df['A'].apply(id)`, I get all different numbers, different to `id(np.nan)`, but if I set `dtype=object`, everything works as OP expected.

Comment: So instead of *"`np.nan` is not comparable"*, the equivalent advice is "don't compare numbers by identity", or as [abarnert said](/a/52124176/4518341) *"As a general rule, if your code relies on two equal values of an immutable type being identical or not being identical, your code is wrong."*.