# What is the difference between pd.isnull(), np.isnan(), Series.isnull(), and 'is np.nan'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In this question, [Pandas Lambda Function with Nan Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061607/pandas-lambda-function-with-nan-support/56392974#56392974,the) first answer says to use `pd.isnull()`, but it is invalid after I use it. In another question, [dataframe.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531503/pandas-dataframe-applylambad-x-x-is-np-nan-does-not-work), the way the questioner works is working for me. Why is this? I use pandas 0.24.2 and numpy 1.13.1

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392974/9817585

Comment: What do you mean by "it is invalid after I use it"?

Comment: Based on your answer you linked, the reason it's not working properly (what you're calling "invalid"?) is because you just made a typo: `if pd.isnull(...)` should have been `if not pd.isnull(...)`. Normally I'd vote to close the question as "caused by a typo", but there's more to this one. (cont'd...)

Comment: Regarding "the way the questioner works is working for me", I found another question that's a better duplicate target for that question and I added it here too. TLDR, if you have a column of object dtype that contains `np.nan`, it'll work, but it won't work in any other case, including other NaNs for example: `s = pd.Series([1, np.nan, float('nan')], dtype='object'); s.apply(lambda x: x is np.nan).values` → `[False  True False]` vs `s.isna().values` → `[False  True  True]`

Comment: BTW, [piRSquared's answer](/a/38531540/4518341) on "dataframe.apply..." doesn't directly answer the question and I left a comment to that effect with an explanation.

Comment: Lastly, the question in the title is too broad for Stack Overflow. You can research the differences for yourself (like in the docs and other existing questions), and if you're still confused, ask a more specific question, or at least add what you've found. See [ask].

Answer (score -1):

I am the questioner. So far, I still don't know the deeper reason, but I have these experiences, for object, use `is np.nan()` or `pd.isna()`. For a float, use `np.isnan()` or `pd.isna()`. always works with `pd.isna()`

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30749363)

Comment: `np.nan()` is not callable. You meant `is np.nan`, right? I'm not sure if you might have meant `np.isnan()`.

Comment: (Just to repeat what I commented on the question, don't use `is np.nan`. It only happened to work in this case.)